# BB10 OS Version using Android Code

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-android

In Android Code the function Build.VERSION.RELEASE returns the android version of device running the application but After porting in BlackBerry the same code doesn't provide the BlackBerry OS version.

Is there any way to get blackberry OS version by porting Android code on BlackBerry.